# Building a website for a hotel - is WordPress the best idea?

Tags: wordpress, web

I'm researching to see if building a full website for a hotel be a good idea to do on WordPress.

I read that wordpress is okay but there are better options.
I want to design and code my own front end look to the website, but have the backend on a stable platform that can take all the reservations seamlessly.

My main concern is to be able to have a backup of all the files and easily switch to another server in case something goes wrong.

I can host the website on my server or host with the service you suggest that comes with the platform all together.

Any ideas and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other options, no doubt, but **yes**, it can and is really possible to build it using WordPress as CMS.

If you want to design and code your own theme, you'll need to study the WordPress Theme Structure and, since you'll build it by yourself, you'll also need to develop plugins to create *custom post types* (aka CPT) to make the hotel management easier on the WP back-end.

About the theme structure, files, child themes and everything, I'd recommend you to read https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

About the plugins development: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

About Custom Post Types: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/

About the backup: it's super easy and you can even make a full backup using free plugins via back-end. But if the site goes down you can easily do it via FTP downloading only wp-content folder and the database. It's really simple to migrate from one WordPress to another, or from host to host.

About the hosting, you'll need to use a server if you want to build this project. There's a difference between wordpress.com and wordpress.org
The .com is simpler, you are not able to build everything you want. The .org is the open source project, which you get the files, upload to your server and connect to database (MariaDB or MySQL). Most hosts offer automatic installation for WordPress and, from there, you can change whatever you want and need.

**Note**: many developers create CPTs INSIDE the theme's code, but this is not recommended by WP as you can see in *We recommend that you put custom post types in a plugin rather than a theme. This ensures that user content remains portable even if they change their theme.*

WP is not really hard, after 1 week studying you'll see yourself getting over most difficulties. Even if it takes longer, don't give up. There's a huge community to help you with WP questions.

Hope it helps and I'm sorry my bad writing, I'm not an english native speaker.

C ya

Comment: Thank you for the effort with your reply. My question isn't geared towards me learning WP, I know WP. The question is if it's the right choice for the project I have.